# String To Decimal by Ignoring Null Fields

Tags: java, swing, jasper-reports, classcastexception

I have a table with accounting data like debit, credit and balance fields which has number values with `varchar` data type. In my java application I'm using `iReport` for report creation and I want to convert those fields to `BigDecimal` and add fields in columns by grouping them with their ID. But the problem I'm facing is there are many empty fields like when there is value in the credit column the debit column will be empty so during converting when the null value appears the following error message displayed and report will not displayed:

```
Error filling print... 
java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Number java.lang.ClassCastException:
```

The only thing I want is that how can I set the null values to 0 or 0.00 so that I can change the `String` to `Decimal` and do the group addition on the report?

I have tried this to set null values to 0.00:

```
($F{itemledgerreport2_DebitAmt} != null) ? $F{itemledgerreport2_DebitAmt} : 0.00
```

It doesn't work I have tried different "string to decimal" conversion methods but the problem is still in the `null` fields.

Any help please, I'm stuck with this to deliver my project.

Comment: Can you change the type of the fields to `java.math.BigDecimal` and then coalesce the null values into `0` so that you never have NULL fields?  The only difference is that you can't perform logic on Null vs 0 (incase that matters).

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. I just cast the varchar to decimal and I removed commas in the iReport query builder like

```sql
CAST(REPLACE(account1.DebitAmt,',', '') AS DECIMAL( 10, 2 )) AS account1_DebitAmt
```

This allows me to easily convert the varchar to decimal and sum up the rows using group summation.

Answer (score -1):

The logic is if null.
!=null should be ==null